# How to create an academic table formatting in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to format and style tables and Google Docs in a similar design as commonly used in academic articles published in peer-reviewed journals?

**Example of an academic table formatting:**

[image: Example of an academic format]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google documents the cell borders should be the same for the four sides of the cell, so at this time it's not possible to format a table using the Google Documents built-in features.

It's worth to say that Google Spreadsheets allows to set different borders for each side of the cell, but there isn't an option to change the border thickness.

One alternative is to use an image editor, like Google Drawings, that allows to insert tables and to draw lines with custom thickness over the cell borders.

#### References

[Add and edit tables - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1696711?hl=en)
[Insert an image - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/97447?hl=en)
[Insert a drawing into another doc type - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179708?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example formatting? With the default tools available I was not able to format it the way as shown above.

Comment: @orshiro. Sorry, I assumed that the table toolbar was the same for documents and spreadsheets but it isn't. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got here by searching how I could format the borders individually, which I thought would be the case for the table.

Select the table's row or cell you want to edit and click the inverted triangle that appears on the right and choose which border you want to edit:

[image]

After that, the border is selected and you can edit it on it's own, change thickness, color or hide it.

All credits to the blog:
https://bazroberts.wordpress.com/2016/04/14/google-docs-getting-to-grips-with-tables/

Comment: I do not see any mentioning of academic tables there.

Comment: There's also no useful information here. We like answers to be self-contained. By all means link to your source, but the answer should stand on its own.

Comment: Ok, gave it another shot.

But there really is no academic mentioning, just tools to make it look like one, no default. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: This is the correct answer and does not deserve the downvotes.